# Finding mean coordinates of cluster of points from point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, vector, clustering, point-creation

I have a set of coordinate points. The points are distributed in such a way that some points are clustered around a specific area. There is an option to find out mean coordinates(s) of the whole point layer.

I would like to know if there is any way in QGIS to find out the mean coordinates of the points from a specific area from a point layer.

Comment: Can you just select the points you want in the attribute table and just average the x and y values of the selected points.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

You need to do this in a two-stage process using the `Vector > Analysis Tools > Mean Coordinates` tool in the second step. This tool will return the mean coordinates for sets of point within a layer if they have a unique `"ID"` field.  So, if you have a polygon layer which defines your areas, do a spatial join (`Vector > Data Management > Join attributes by location`) to attribute your points with the polygon (area) id and then use the Mean coordinates tool, specifying the new field.

You may already have unique `"ID"`s or a polygon layer but if you do not you could create a fishnet (`Vector > Research Tools > Vector Grid`) to lay over the points as one method to define the areas. Alternatively, if your areas are defined by a raster layer, then you could use the [Point sampling](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/) plugin to attribute the points based on your raster. Or, if you want to attribute them by location without a vector or raster layer, you will need to create an algorithm to give a new attribute based on the coordinates of each point (possibly using some modulus-based approach).